# Comparing before and after survey using Likert Scale

Tags: t-test, likert, parametric

We are trying to measure if there is a difference on the level of interests of participants before and after I let them play a game. The survey is in the form of Likert Scale where `1 - Not at all Interested, 2 - Not Very Interested, 3- Neutral, 4 - Somewhat Interested, 5 - Very Interested`. There are 50 participants of this study.

We are looking to use a parametric test in this group called paired t-test. Where we get the mean of each participant from (before the game) then we get again the average weighted mean (after the game) in order to find if there is a difference on their level of interest using paired t-test. Is it appropriate to use this parametric test in our study?

Comment: Treating an ordinal Likert scale as if numerical and betting on meaningful normally distributed averages for a paired t test at the end may or may not work. You should be prepared to switch to a paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test if necessary, // Can you give an idea what the weighted means might look like? Out of orig'l 5 'points' what size difference before vs. after your 'game' would you consider to be meaningful in practical terms? // If you can give extra info, then I (or someone else here) _might_ be able to give an idea whether 50 participants is enough.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited it to weighted mean -> mean.
Suppose there are 50 participants and each of these participants will be given a survey. The mean will be calculated by adding the overall score divided by the number of questions. Example there are 5 questions and we have this participant's response ( 3 , 1 , 5, 4 , 5 ). The mean will be 3.6. Then each participant has an equivalent mean mapped to them. ( 50 participants have different means) , then this will then be compared using t-test? assuming that the data is normally distributed. Is this process correct?

Comment: Such uses of Likert data are common, but often IMHO inappropriate. Unless the difference between 1 and 2 on the Likert-5 scale is as 'important' as the difference between 3 and 4, the ordinal data may not 'average' meaningfully. // Do you know if this 'game' and this survey have been used for similar purposes before? and if so, led to meaningful results? How much variability in differences, before vs. after, do you expect? // You're being vague about this project and expectations for it. // Unless you know a lot more about this project than you're telling, I can't predict success.